# View "dat://" Websites in a GeckoFx Web Browser

Tags: c#, winforms, integration, geckofx, dat-protocol

I'm building a blockchain-themed web browser in a **C# .NET Windows Form Application** and want to allow users to view sites using the dat:// protocol. I have found several repositories online but none of them seem to be for C# or close to what I want.

I've already tried using the [Dat P2P Protocol](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dat-p2p-protocol/) Firefox addon but the setup was too difficult and I'd have to figure out how to add extensions to the browser in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there's only one implementation of Dat, which is built for NodeJS. There's a rust implementation being developed as well.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there any way that I could use Rust to work with the GeckoFx browser engine in order to run dat protocol-based websites?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with those stacks to answer.